# how to handle combo boxes of ExtJS in selenium webdriver

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver

Hi i have a ExtJS based UI. I have come to know that in ExtJS the combo box is not a real combo box but a combination of input text field, image of drop down box and a list. Now i am able to identify the control but i am stuck at selecting the value from the list. In the HTML source i see that the list is appearing as a seperate div and gets attached at the end of the source when we click on the drop down. find below the HTML source of the drop down control.
{

```
<div id="ext-gen678" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-btn-plugin-wrap" style="width: 556px;">
<div id="ext-gen676" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap x-trigger-wrap-focus" style="width: 521px;">
<input id="ext-gen677" type="hidden" name="GHVOg:#concat#~inputFld~ISGP_UNIV:ft_t_isgp.prnt_iss_grp_oid:0" value="">
<input id="GHVOg:Mixh8:0" class="x-form-text x-form-field gs_dropDown_input gs_req x-form-invalid x-form-focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" size="24" style="width: 504px;">
<img id="trigger-GHVOg:Mixh8:0" class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" alt="" src="../../ext/resources/images/default/s.gif">
```

}

find below the HTML source of the drop down list:

```
<div id="ext-gen726" class="x-layer x-combo-list x-resizable-pinned" style="position: absolute; z-index: 12007; visibility: visible; left: 294px; top: 370px; width: 554px; height: 123px; font-size: 11px;">
<div id="ext-gen727" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 554px; margin-bottom: 8px; height: 114px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item"></div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">12h Universe</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">1h Universe</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">24h Universe</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">2h Universe</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">4h Universe</div>
```

Now i have problem selecting the value from the list as the div element of the list is not attached to the control.
Also please refer the screen shot, where i have multiple similar controls [Named "Add Security to Universe"]
[image: Screenshot of the ExtJS UI]

In the screen shot you can see multiple drop downs [Add security to Universe] highlighted and all the drop downs have same value appearing in the list. so how can i identify these values from the drop down list.
I was wondering how ExtJS maintains mapping of the drop down div elements with the combo Box widget so that i could use the same logic for identifying the list. Can anyone tell me how can i go about doing this thing in selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you notice that there will be only one visible `x-combo-list` on the page? (Let me know if you can open up two combo lists at the same time)

Therefore you only need to care about the visible one `x-combo-list`.

Css selector: `.x-combo-list[style*='visibility: visible;'] .x-combo-list-item`

Xpath: `//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list') and contains(@style, 'visibility: visible;')]//*[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list-item')]`

```java
// untested java code, just for the logic
public void clickComboItem(WebElement input, String target) {
    input.click(); // click input to pop up the combo list
    List<WebElement> comboItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".x-combo-list[style*='visibility: visible;'] .x-combo-list-item"));
    for (int i = 0; i <= comboItems.size(); i++) {
        WebElement item = comboItems.get(i);
        if (item.getText().eqauls(target)) {
            item.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```c#
// compilable C# version
public void ClickComboItem(IWebElement input, string target) {
    input.Click();
    IList<IWebElement> comboItems = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector(".x-combo-list[style*='visibility: visible;'] .x-combo-list-item"));
    comboItems.First(item => item.Text.Trim() == target).Click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had played around for hours, and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest is :

you catch all your inputs like :

```
List<WebElement> inputList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input cssSelector")); // you must complete this cssSelector
WebElement input = inputList.get(0); // get the 1st input
input.click(); //click on the first input and the option list appears.
```

you catch all "options" like :

```
List<WebElement> optionList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".x-combo-list-item")); // get all options
WebElement option = optionList.get(1);
option.click();
input.sendKeys(option.getText()); //getText() get the html inner value
```

This is just an example in **Java** and you can actually use a loop `foreach` if you want to automat this populate for all your `inputs`.

Comment: Hi @e1che my problem is linking of drop down control with the list that it shows. Lets say i wish to select a value for 3rd combo-box drop down so how can i do it coz in the HTML source if i will try to search the value by the text i.e present in the list i will get multiple such controls. and also it is very risky coz the same value may appear in some other drop down list too. lets say for an example there are 2 combo-box which have stored integers in their list now how can i select value in this two combo-boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScriptExecutor, my SelectRandomOption looks like this:

```
public void SelectRandomOption()
{
    String randomOptionIndex = "Math.floor(Math.random()*Ext.getCmp('" + ExtJSIdOfComboBox + "').getStore().getCount()-1)";
    String randomOptionValue = "Ext.getCmp('" + ExtJSIdOfComboBox + "').getStore().getAt(" + randomOptionIndex + ").getData()['model']";
    String jsScript = "Ext.getCmp('" + ExtJSIdOfComboBox + "').setValue(" + randomOptionValue + ");";
    js.ExecuteScript(jsScript);
}
```

Comment: I agree. But in this case I would prefer JavaScriptExecutor anyway. Simply because in ExtJS there are often 'onselect', 'onclick' and other listeners that may be difficult (or even impossible) to achieve with pure selenium driver.

Answer (score 0):

I basically used the marked answer above however it needed a bit of adapting for Ext Js 4.1.

It's essentially the same approach but you need to look for a visible div marked with class "x-boundlist"

I used xpath and used queries that looked something like this:

```
.//div[@class[contains(.,'x-boundlist')]]
```

and then retrieve and click on an li matching your desired entry:

```
.//li[normalize-space(text())='combobox entry text']
```

I've put normalize-space in there as xpath seems to have real problems if you dont trim strings.  That methods does a left + right trim and also removes duplicate spaces eg
`' blah     blah '` would change to `'blah blah'`.