# ExtJS Combo Boxes having Same Xpath ,IDs,CSS paths with dynamically changing IDS and able to choose drop down element using Selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am really stuck in testing an extJS web based application which contains many drop down combo boxes. and each box have the same class name and ids are dynamically changing each time the page gets loaded.

The combo boxes is not a typical drop down box. It contains a text box, followed by drop down button image and then clicking on that drop down button providese all the options in the drop down box. I want to select a particular element from the drop down box . 
When inspect the drop down button element using firepath, its html code is

```
<div id="ext-gen1103" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-first" role="button"/>
```

similarly if i inpsect the drop down text box (whose id alone is constant and does not change)the html code is

```
<input id="NSClientCombo-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus x-field-form-focus x-field-default-form-focus" type="text" placeholder="Select One" name="NSClientCombo" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%; height: 28px;"/>
```

and if i inspect any of the drop down elements the html code for that is

```
<div id="boundlist-1048-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; height: 187px;">
   <ul class="x-list-plain">
      <li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">****HELP NG****</li>
      <li class="x-boundlist-item" unselectable="on" role="option">ABC Inc.</li>
```

I want to choose "HELP NG" or ""ABC Inc"" from drop down box. But i am really struck how to integrate and how to write selenium webdriver code to choose an element from drop down box since the drop down button contains only id and class (id keeps changing and class name for all the other drop down buttons are same). Have anyone crossed across such scenerios and please help me in sorting out this issue since this is taking away the time totally.:(

Comment: When you post HTML or code, please indent each line with 4 spaces and take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: You should also specify the language you are using in the question and tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ext.getCmp() function to retrieve a webElement of this combo. 
see the code below.

This code will return the web Element

```
public static IWebElement ExtJsGetWebElementById(this IWebDriver driver, string id)
        {

            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

            var script = "return Ext.getCmp('" + id + "').el.dom";
            var Element = js.ExecuteScript(script) as IWebElement;
            return Element;

        }
```

The next function will be used to open the combo box and set a particular value to it using keyboard shortcuts.

```
 public static void ExtJsSetComboValueWithKeyBoard(this IWebDriver driver, string comboId, string valueToSet)
        {

            var element = driver.ExtJsGetWebElementById(comboId);
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);         

            element.SendKeys(valueToSet);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

        }
```

to Use the above method, use it like this in your test case.

```
_webDriver.ExtJsSetComboValueWithKeyBoard("NSClientCombo","ABC Inc.");
```

Comment: Also see this link which is using a slightly different approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296490/how-to-handle-combo-boxes-of-extjs-in-selenium-webdriver/16326906#16326906